# Calling MS Access Stored Queries with Parameters using DAAB v5.0

Tags: ms-access, daab

I wanted to find out if it is possible to call MS Access Stored Queries with parameters using DAAB.

I am using the Northwind sample database to test this scenario I have created the following Stored Query with parameter in MS Access:

```
PARAMETERS FirstName Text ( 255 );
SELECT Employees.ID
FROM Employees
WHERE (((Employees.[First Name])=[@FirstName]));
```

This query is stored with name: `GetEmployeeIDByName`

I have created a wrapper over the DAAB to allow access to various databases like SQL, Oracle, any OLEDB and and ODBC database.

Below is the sample code for my test:

```
Database db = new GenericDatabase("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\Database\Access\Northwind 20071.accdb",OleDbFactory.Instance);

DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcedure("GetEmployeeIDByName");

db.AddInParameter(cmd,"@FirstName",DbType.String,40);

object employeeID = db.ExecuteScalar();
```

I get an error Invalid Operation. I am not sure if I am calling the stored Queries correctly as I am able to call Stored Queries that do not have any parameter without any errors.

Comment: The @ is not used for parameters in Jet/ACE SQL.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue. The issue was with the Northwind sample database. I then imported Northwind database from SQL Server into MS Access and also created the stored queries in MS Access.

Here is the detailed discussion that I had with the Enterprise Library DAAB's team:
http://entlib.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=223653
Hope it helps.

Access does not care about the @ character you can call the parameter with or without the @ character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue. The issue was with the Northwind sample database. I then imported Northwind database from SQL Server into MS Access and also created the stored queries in MS Access. Here is the detailed discussion that I had with the Enterprise Library DAAB's team: entlib.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=223653 Hope it helps. Access does not care about the @ character you can call the parameter with or without the @ character.

Comment: In SQL dialects where the @ is used for parameters, what is the name of the parameter referred to by @FirstName? In Jet/ACE, the parameter name is @FirstName, but in SQL dialects where @ is used to delineate a parameter, is the parameter name not FirstName? I'm an Access developer and haven't used those other SQL dialects, so I could just be confused here.